# clang rejects derived reference argument (just fine with g++)

Tags: c++, clang

Why does the following not compile in clang, but compiles just as expected in g++?

```
#include <valarray>

class Array : public std::valarray<double> {
public:
    Array(unsigned i=0) : std::valarray<double>(i) {}
};

int main() 
{
    Array a(3);
    for(int j=0; j<3; ++j) a[j]=j + 1; 

    std::valarray<double> b = std::exp(a);
}
```

This example was distilled to bare bones from a much more complicated situation, but the usual experiments show no issues:

After changing:

```
Array a(3)
```

to

```
std::valarray<double> a(3)
```

the code compiles just fine.

Using
    static_cast< std::valarray >(a)
also works fine.

As requested by M.M. in the comments, the clang version is:

```
> clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Indeed as pointed out by "Baum mit Augen" if I add

```
-stdlib=libstdc++
```

to the compilation arguments it compiles just fine.

Comment: where is the "derived reference argument" you mention in the title ?

Comment: The code [compiles in clang](http://goo.gl/jsoxeM) 3.5.0, 3.6, 3.7.0, and 3.8.0.   Please include in the question the exact compiler version. Perhaps this is a library issue so also include which library and version your clang installation is using.

Comment: There is a definition of std::exp for valarrays in the valarray header

Comment: @M.M Doesn't compile with libc++ though. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecaaefe178314e18

Comment: My money is on gcc, I can't find anything that forbids this. I am not confident enough to write an answer though. For the record, `std::valarray` already is weird enough and considered a bad idea by many on its own, adding complexity by inheriting from it has a pretty high chance to get you into trouble.

Comment: @BaummitAugen that's a different error tho (the header for `std::exp` is not included)

Comment: std::exp for valarray is defined in the <valarray> header.

As for using valarray, instead of other containers, the overloaded math functions (e.g. exp, sin, ...) are a great reason to do so. It results in much more readable code, rather than having to muck with algorithms and such.

Comment: @M.M That does not change anything. (in the result with clang, that is)

Comment: There's [a patch](http://reviews.llvm.org/D13289) that should fix this issue in libc++; it's awaiting review. Also note the discussion here: http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2015-September/045224.html http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2015-October/045261.html